# LINQ to SQL & Stored Procedure return type

Tags: linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PurgeFoo
AS
  DELETE FROM Foo
  RETURN @@ROWCOUNT
```

I've added this stored procedure to my DBML, but the Return Type is "(Auto-generated Type)" but I'm an int.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** 
Dropped and re-created the store procedure and removed it from the DBML.  Now, the return type is "(None")

Comment: Hmm... strange.. I did the very same thing - in my case, the method `.PurgeFoo()` on my LINQ Data Context does indeed return a `INT` from its call.... Have you tried removing and re-adding that stored proc from your DBML model?? If you had updated it after adding it, the model wouldn't have picked up that update...

Comment: I have removed and added it back but the return type is still "(None)".  However, I tried to call the .PurgeFoo() and it does return an INT even though the return type says otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the return to a SELECT. This way, you get a proper recordset.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PurgeFoo
AS
DELETE FROM Foo
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT AS RowsDeleted
GO
```

Or an OUTPUT parameter, like so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PurgeFoo
  @RowsDeleted int = 0 OUTPUT
AS
DELETE FROM Foo
SET @RowsDeleted =  @@ROWCOUNT
GO
```

The RETURN value is most useful for status and error codes, not meaningful data.

Comment: I totally get your point (and agree) regarding the RETURN value should be used for status and error codes.  I simplified my stored procedure in this question easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

Why not do a SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Foo to count the rows before you delete them since all rows are deleted? Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE PurgeFoo
@Rows INT OUTPUT
AS
SET @Rows = SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Foo
DELETE FROM Foo
```

Then when you call the SP, you can get value of the output parameter as an INT. Also, you can change the * to which ever column you want to make the SELECT statement run faster.

Comment: I also tried that but I don't want to create a new parameter just to get the no. of records affected.